# Need advice for guitar amplification in church

Tags: amplification

I've recently started going to a church and have started to play the guitar there. I have a semi acoustic so can plug in. There is another guitarist aswell, and we both sing. 
The problem is that there mixing desk at the back of church only has 4 channels. So we can't really plug into the sound system as other microphones are needed.
I have no idea about amps and what would be suitable for us. Should we get two small amps or a larger one? Can we somehow increase the number of channels that plug into the main mixer?
Thankyou!
Rachael

Comment: Rachael, please log back into your account to edit your question so you can also upvote and mark as accepted any answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just get another mixer is the cheapest, cheerfulest option. If you had, say a 4 channel mixer, it would output into one p.a. channel, giving 7 altogether. Assuming there's eq on each p.a. channel, along with gain, just about all the adjustents that need to be made can be done, maybe remotely if you have a good long balanced lead twixt mixer and p.a. If you need 4 mics, either they all plug into mixer, or 3 into p.a. and last one into mixer.

Comment: The follow-up question is, which is a better way to spend the money - buying a second four-channel mixer or buying an 8 or 12 channel mixer and replacing/selling the current 4 channel mixer?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - yes, I considered that option, but unsure that the original 'mixer' is actually just that. Could well be a 4 channel amp for p.a., as one would hardly buy an only 4 channel mixer as original eqipment. But yes, replace the lot with at least an 8 channel mixer/amp/spkrs.

Answer (score 0):

Rachel,

I mixer (on stage with an output for both guitars makes a lot of sense).

Optionally, consider a suitable amp that accepts 1 inputs and the additional benefit might be the ability to use this amp for your on stage
monitoring of you sound. If the soundboard set up has monitors then this may not be a great idea because I'm sure you'll want to hear the vocals.

If the set up has no monitoring at all, I'd run a stage mixer with output to monitors and an output for the house board at the back so you can hear vocals, guitars and just let the house mix be concerned with the audiences mix.

If you think at some point you'll make music beyond the church that might help guide the $'s you spent to solve the current problem like a small powered mixer with some speakers or a small PA with speakers for your own needs.

McD